# Matlab's Mex-file using a vector class definition

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to create a Mex-file from a C++ code source file to use it with Matlab. I have compiling errors due to the vector class definition handling that I do not understand very well. I would like to know how I should modify the code to work. Below I show the relevant code's parts that I have divided into four sections for clarifying more (Computational code, MexFunction code, Vector class definition and compiling errors):

#### Computational routine's code:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "SAT_VecMat.h"

void AccelSolrad (const Vector& r, const Vector& r_Sun, double Area, double mass,
    double CR, double P0, double AU,const Vector& Accel )
```

#### mexFunction's code:

```
...
const Vector& r_sat(3);       // dummy argument name for r
const Vector& r_sol(3);       // dummy argument name for r_Sun      
const Vector& outMatrix(3);   // dummy argument name for Accel
...
r_sat = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
r_sol = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,3,mxREAL);
outMatrix = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
```

#### Vector class definition included in SAT_VecMat.h:

```
class Vector
{

  public:

    friend class Matrix;

    // Constructors    
    Vector ();                              // Vector without elements
    Vector (int Size);                      // Nullvector of specified size 
    Vector (const Vector& V);               // Vector copy
    Vector (const double* p, int N);        // Array copy
    Vector (double x, double y, double z);  // 3dim-Vector
    Vector (double x, double y, double z,   // 6dim-Vector
            double X, double Y, double Z);  

    // Destructor
    ~Vector();

    // Size
    int size() const { return n; };
    Vector& resize(int Size);

    // Assignment
    Vector& operator=(const double value);
    Vector& operator=(const Vector& V);

    // Component access (Fortran notation)
    double  operator () (int i) const { return v[i]; };
    double& operator () (int i)       { return v[i]; };
    Vector slice (int first, int last) const;
...
```

#### Compiling errors:

```
    >> mex AccelSolrad.cpp

    AccelSolrad.cpp 

    c:\program files\matlab\r2009b\extern\include\matrix.h(332) : error C2371: 'char16_t' : redefinition; different basic types

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\yvals.h(576) : see declaration of 'char16_t' 

AccelSolrad.cpp(14) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(69): could be 'Vector &Vector::operator =(const double)' 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(70): or       'Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector &)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(const Vector, Vector)' 

AccelSolrad.cpp(18) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(69): could be 'Vector &Vector::operator =(const double)' 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(70): or       'Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector &)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(const Vector, Vector)' 

AccelSolrad.cpp(94) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(69): could be 'Vector &Vector::operator =(const double)' 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(70): or       'Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector &)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(const Vector, double *)' 

AccelSolrad.cpp(96) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(69): could be 'Vector &Vector::operator =(const double)' 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(70): or       'Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector &)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(const Vector, double *)' 

AccelSolrad.cpp(112) : error C2678: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const Vector' (or there is no acceptable conversion) 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(69): could be 'Vector &Vector::operator =(const double)' 
        d:\po\ejemplos\SAT_VecMat.h(70): or       'Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector &)' 
        while trying to match the argument list '(const Vector, double *)' 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2009B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'AccelSolrad.cpp' failed.
```

Comment: @0A0D: The question is how to modify the AccelSolrad (in particular, I think that it would be the code lines that use Vector class definition and those that operating with the Vectors r_sat,r, r_Sun and r_sol) r_Sun

Comment: @Amro: I am grateful for your editing. Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update:

At least the error message about `char16_t` is likely due to the fact that you are using Visual Studio 2010 with MATLAB R2009b.  That compiler is too new for this version of MATLAB. See the[Supported Compilers list for R2009b](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2009b/).

Not too clear about the other errors, but:

```
 Vector& r_sat(3);
```

Seems to me to be pretty questionable C++: Since it is a reference to a vector, what you are doing is creating a temporary Vector with size 3, then initializing the reference to refer to that temporary.
Better to just declare `r_sat` as `Vector`.

Then later you have:

```
r_sat = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
```

The `mxGetPr()` function returns a pointer to a double array, but the Vector class does not have an `operator=` that takes a `double*` as an argument.

Maybe something like this:

```
r_sat = Vector(mxGetPr(prhs[0]), 3); // use the Vector(double*, int N) constructor
```

### Previous answer:

1. Your `Vector` class is C++, not C.
2. Since you are on Windows, the `lcc` compiler that ships with MATLAB is a C compiler, it does not understand C++.  If you are going to be compiling C++ MEX files, you will need to run `mex -setup` and pick a supported C++ compiler (typically, Visual Studio).
3. The way `mex` decides whether you're building a C or C++ MEX file (which influences whether it invokes the C or C++ compiler to do the actual compiling and linking) is based on the file extension.  So rename `AccelSolrad.c` to `AccelSolrad.cpp` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. You are right. The source code file is really C++ and I am using Visual Studio as compiler. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have something....though I've never worked with `const obj&` before.

You're instancing the vector class in your main code as a constant:

```
const Vector& r_sat(3);
```

Then you're trying to assign to the vector r_span an array. Since r_span was declared constant you can't. You have to do that as part of the constructor.